# Is owl:complementOf same as owl:disjointWith in RDF?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl

I am puzzled about their real meaning. Say if we have a class mate, then we can define anything that is not mate as a class "notMat". So we can use owl:complementOf here. But what about Man and women? Can we use owl:complementOf  to say that a "woman" is not a "man"? if not, then is there any way to describe the disjointness of man and woman class without using  `owl:disjointWith`?

Can we use a property "disjoint" in both class and then use this property as a predicate in triples whose subjects and objects are "man" and "woman" class to describe the disjointness?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that the complement of a class A is the class B such that A union B is equivalent to Top (Thing, Resource, or whatever represents all the individuals in your interpretation), while disjoint only means that A and B do not share individuals.

For example, if we say that all our individuals are mammals, you can say that Male is the complement of Female. However, if the individuals are all mammals and all trees, then Male and Female are no longer the complement of each other, because there are trees, which are neither. However the two classes are still disjoint.

Comment: alright. So if I do not want to use Mammals as universal set, then is there any other way to make man and woman disjoint without using owl:disjointWith?

Comment: They can be implicitly disjoint; for example, there could be a property that is mandatory for woman (e.g., Woman subClassOf minCardinality 1 P) and forbidden for man (Man subclassOf maxCardinality 0 P).

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid owl:disjointWith? The complexity of reasoning is the same whether owl:disjointWith is used explicitly, or the same purpose is reached through syntactic tricks like the one above.

Comment: I was thinking like is I define a man class and a woman class, then they are actually disjoint. But anybody can make a subclass with both parent man and woman. Thus if I don't use owl:disjointWith, the subclass would be man and woman at the same time. So I was looking for other ways to make them disjoint. Thank you for your help.